# Extracción de un solo enlace

Tags: python, web, scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

me gustaría extraer el enlace del encabezado.

en la funcion parse, vereis una variable "enlace" que está vacia.
Quiero extraer el mismo enlace que es el h2.

Supongo que en vez de extraer el TEXT, debo extraer el LINK, pero no se como se hace.

Alguien conoce un método o una función que encaje ahí? Gracias

```
    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        contenedor_noticias = soup.find_all('table', class_="serpContainerMinHeight")
        for contenedor in contenedor_noticias:
            noticias = contenedor.find_all('div', class_="jobsearch-SerpJobCard")
            for noticia in noticias:
                item = ItemLoader(Noticia(), response.body)


                titular = noticia.find('h2').text.replace('\n', '').replace('nueva', '')
                descripcion = noticia.find(class_="summary").text.replace('\n', ' ')
                empresa = noticia.find(class_="company").text
                ciudad = noticia.find(class_="location").text
                enlace =
           

                print(enlace)

                if (descripcion != None):
                    descripcion = descripcion
                else:
                    descripcion = "N/A"

                print()
                item.add_value('titular', titular)
                item.add_value('descripcion', descripcion)
                item.add_value('empresa', empresa)
                item.add_value('ciudad', ciudad)
                item.add_value('enlace', enlace)
                pedir_id_para_editar(titular, descripcion, empresa, ciudad, enlace)
                yield item.load_item()
```

Comment: quieres extraer el enlace que esta en la variable `titular`?

Comment: No sabria decirte, ese h2 es asi <h2><a><\a</2>. Quiero sacar ese enlace. Yo me refiero a si hay una manera general de sacarlo, utilizo scrapy y beautiful soup. De igual firma que utilizo .text para sacar el titulo, como puedo sacar el enlace dentro del href??

Comment: utiliza una expresión regular